# Rewrite URL redirect

Tags: redirect, iis, http-redirect

I am trying to re-write a URL from this address:

https://merchant.test-01.mysite.co/payment-gateway/vend?amount=69.90&register_id=12&currency=NZD

To this address:

https://mysite.co/nz/test-01/merchant/payment-gateway/vend?amount=69.90&register_id=12&currency=NZD

I try this:

```
<rule name="test01Generic" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(\S+?).test-01.mysite.co$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.co/nz/test-01/{C:1}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

With this result:

https://mysite.co/nz/test-01/merchant?amount=69.90&register_id=12&currency=NZD

Where `payment-gateway/vend` is missing

And this

```
<rule name="test01Generic" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(\S+?).test-01.mysite.co$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.co/nz/test-01/{C:1}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

With this result:

https://mysite.co/nz/test-01/merchant/payment-gateway/vend?amount=69.90&register_id=12&currency=NZD&amount=69.90&register_id=12&currency=NZD

The query parameters double up.

Any ideas on what am I missing?

Comment: A redirection isn't the same thing as a rewrite. Also, are you thinking of using ARR instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work it out, I had to change `{REQUEST_URI}` to `{PATH_INFO}`

```
<rule name="test01Generic" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(\S+?).test-01.mysite.co$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.co/nz/test-01/{C:1}{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

Now when the address bellow is called:

https://merchant.test-01.mysite.co/payment-gateway/vend?amount=69.90&register_id=12&currency=NZD

I'm redirecting to this address:

https://mysite.co/nz/test-01/merchant/payment-gateway/vend?amount=69.90&register_id=12&currency=NZD

Answer (score 0):

Please modify {REQUEST_URI} to {URL} and leave appendQueryStrin to true, then it would work.

```
 <rule name="test0Generic" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(\S+?).test-01.mysite.co$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.co/nz/test-01/{C:1}{URL}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

[image]